# Getting inner html with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript/jQuery block as a callback after $.get function:

```
function myCallBack(data, textStatus) {
  var text1 = $(data).html();
  document.write(text1);
}
```

The data contains html data ok. I'd like to strip the html and get only inner html into text1 variable. For some reason it doesn't work. Firebug kinda "crashes" upon executing line 'var text1 = ...'

**Edited**:

My **data** variable contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/…;\r\n\r\n<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">;\r\n
<head>\r\n 
<title></title>\r\n
</head>\r\n
<body>\r\n Testing...\r\n</body>\r\n
</html>\r\n
```

And I'd like to parse the part between body tags.

Comment: Did you try `innerHTML`?

Comment: Just tried. 

var text1 = data.innerHTML;

Returns "undefined".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean you want the inner text?

```
var text1 = $(data).text();
```

**[Update]**

Try it with this regular expression:

```
var bodyText = new RegExp(/<body[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/body>/).exec(data)[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. That doesn't work for me however, it returns empty string.

My data variable contains: 

"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n <title></title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n Testing...\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"

And I'd like to parse the part between <body> and </body> tags.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. with find&html() returns null and with find&text() returns "". (an empty string)

Comment: im trying to find a solution atm for this

Comment: posted a solution with a regexp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(data)[1].data
```

But I think that just works with a specific example and not in general.

Answer (score 0):

You perform a webrequest by get. That implies that the result will only be a string.

```
var text1 = data ;
```

Is all you can get. There is no DOM-object you can traverse. You only get this if you access elements on you own page.